# How to Select the Highest Attribute For a Selected Attribute in JSON Using Python

Tags: python, json, list, sorting, discord

**I'm developing a discord bot for fetching the floor price on Solanart. I'm using this JSON:** https://qzlsklfacc.medianetwork.cloud/nft_for_sale?collection=cryptocavemen

How do i select the highest id for the unique token adress ?
Token adress is unique but for one token adress there are many id beacuse of the sales.
**I need to get the latest id for the token adress. Then i need to get the price of the token adress' max id.**

The JSON Snippet:
"id":908471,
"token_add":"8p9LZH6VjfqQhMPoNuT6DyPZnBUje22mhanncdEzLWsv",

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import os
import json
import urllib

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client = discord.Client()

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://qzlsklfacc.medianetwork.cloud/nft_for_sale?collection=cryptocavemen") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('!floor'):
    floor_price = min(map(lambda x: x['price'], data))
    await message.channel.send("The Floor Price is: " + str(floor_price))

client.run(my_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map and filter:

```py
max_ids = []
unique_tokens = set(v["token_add"] for v in data)

for unique_token in unique_tokens:
    max_id = max(
        map(
            lambda x: x["id"],
            list(
                filter(
                    lambda x: x["token_add"] == unique_token,
                    data,
                )
            ),
        )
    )
    max_ids.append({"token_add": unique_token, "max_id": max_id})
```

Returns (some lines):

```py
[ {'max_id': 833785,
  'token_add': 'G32GiuACw5savubWG454kYGcxgHfum4bi8HY4WaC5iKV'},
 {'max_id': 808390,
  'token_add': '6uZ3th4EjovR2X5RJf2SSY6dgTXifEmjyin7RSb5vVYv'},
 {'max_id': 1059873,
  'token_add': 'BZvoMxGMmAHqDLMaEZo7V5WW9P5HzVQBvCgDAbFFyScU'}]
```

Comment: I need that function for every token adress. It should get all of the token adresses and find the biggest id inside the JSON. Not for one unique token, all tokens inside the JSON. Then i need to get the price of the token which has the biggest id.

Comment: Edited as requested. You can get the price based on the `max_id` attribute.

Comment: How do i get the lowest price from the max_ids ? Sorry, I'm new in Python. Please help me for the code.